# What is a ValueError?

Tags: python

I have a simple python script that takes user input:

```
limit=int(input())
answer=1
a=[]
for i in range(limit):
    data=int(input())
    a.append(data)
for j in a:
    answer = answer*j+10**9+7
print(answer)
```

When I run it, I keep getting errors that look like this this.

```
Execution failed.
ValueError: could not convert string to float : '1 2 3 4 5'

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/hackerearth/PYTHON3_12/s_0b.py3", line 5, in 
data=int(float(input()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1 2 3 4 5'
```

What is a `ValueError` and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: It's important to state your specific question clearly. Properly formatted code blocks are also important to make your code readable. Finally, you should use the `python` tag since this is a general python question, not a version specific one. Just a warning, your question will likely be closed since you could find the answer by searching google for your error message (the `ValueError: ...` part of it). Don't be discouraged! Googling error messages is your friend and should be your first step.

Comment: I dont see the issue. You should clearly state the input. I suspect that you are inputting all values on one line, but `input` treats everything before the carriage return as one input, so it expects one value then return another value, return and so on. `3` is convertible to int but `1 2 3 4 5` is not (but `map(int, '1 2 3 4'.split())` works if your result is ok as a list). If you want to input all values on one line, you will need to do some extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse each number one at a time. You are trying to input all of the numbers at once, which will not work. Try this:

```
limit=int(input())
answer=1
a=[]
numbers = input()
toParse = numbers.split(' ') #breaks input string into individual numbers
for i in range(toParse):
    data=int(toParse[i])
    a.append(data)
for j in a:
    answer = answer*j+10**9+7
print(answer)
```

I changed your code to 1) take in the input numbers *before* the loop, then 2) split them into a list where each element is one of the numbers in your original string, which 3) can then be parsed as data in your loop.